# In iOS action extension how to check wether the user is pro or not?

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently working on an app where I have an action extension. I am not able to access the user defaults of the app from the extension. I want to change some result in the action extension if the user is pro. Is there anyway I can do this

Answer (score 0):

You need to create app group in YourProject -> YourTarget -> Capabilities:
[image]

Than create an instance of UserDefaults:

```
let sharedUserDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: groupName)
```

After all of this you can use this instance in your extension:

```
sharedUserDefaults.value(forKey: someKey)
```

Comment: this is not working